# In a JSON array, how to search for a certain record returned by ConvertFrom-Json?

Tags: json, powershell, jwk, select-object, powershell-6.0

With Powershell 6 I am able to download a file in JSON format with:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys |
>> ConvertFrom-Json |
>> Select-Object -expand keys

kty    : RSA
use    : sig
kid    : CtTuhMJmD5M7DLdzD2v2x3QKSRY
x5t    : CtTuhMJmD5M7DLdzD2v2x3QKSRY
n      : 18uZ3P3IgOySlnOsxeIN5WUKzvlm6evPDMFbmXPtTF0GMe7tD2JPfai2UGn74s7AFwqxWO5DQZRu6VfQUux8uMR4J7nxm1Kf__7pVEVJJyDuL5a8PARRYQtH68w-0IZxcFOkgsSdhtIzPQ2jj4mmRzWXIwh8M_8pJ6qiOjvjF9bhEq0CC_f27BnljPaFn8hxY69pCoxenWWqFcsUhFZvCMthhRubAbBilDr74KaXS5xCgySBhPzwekD9_NdCUu
         Csdqavd4T-VWnbplbB8YsC-R00FptBFKuTyT9zoGZjWZilQVmj7v3k8jXqYB2nWKgTAfwjmiyKz78FHkaE-nCIDw
e      : AQAB
x5c    : {MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQXVogj9BAf49IpuOSIvztNDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAtMSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4XDTIwMDMxNzAwMDAwMFoXDTI1MDMxNzAwMDAwMFowLTErMCkGA1UEAxMiYWNjb3VudHMuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBB
         QADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANfLmdz9yIDskpZzrMXiDeVlCs75ZunrzwzBW5lz7UxdBjHu7Q9iT32otlBp++LOwBcKsVjuQ0GUbulX0FLsfLjEeCe58ZtSn//+6VRFSScg7i+WvDwEUWELR+vMPtCGcXBTpILEnYbSMz0No4+Jpkc1lyMIfDP/KSeqojo74xfW4RKtAgv39uwZ5Yz2hZ/IcWOvaQqMXp1lqhXLFIRWbwjLYYUbmwGwYpQ6++Cml0u
         cQoMkgYT88HpA/fzXQlLgrHamr3eE/lVp26ZWwfGLAvkdNBabQRSrk8k/c6BmY1mYpUFZo+795PI16mAdp1ioEwH8I5osis+/BR5GhPpwiA8CAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFF8MDGklOGhGNVJvsHHRCaqtzexcMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCKkegw/mdpCVl1lOpgU4G9RT+1gtcPqZK9kpimuDggSJju6KUQlOCi5/lIH5DCzpjFd
         mG17TjWVBNve5kowmrhLzovY0Ykk7+6hYTBK8dNNSmd4SK7zY++0aDIuOzHP2Cur+kgFC0gez50tPzotLDtMmp40gknXuzltwJfezNSw3gLgljDsGGcDIXK3qLSYh44qSuRGwulcN2EJUZBI9tIxoODpaWHIN8+z2uZvf8JBYFjA3+n9FRQn51X16CTcjq4QRTbNVpgVuQuyaYnEtx0ZnDvguB3RjGSPIXTRBkLl2x7e8/6uAZ6tchw8rhcOtP
         sFgJuoJokGjvcUSR/6Eqd}
issuer : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0

kty    : RSA
use    : sig
kid    : SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI
x5t    : SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI
n      : uHPewhg4WC3eLVPkEFlj7RDtaKYWXCI5G-LPVzsMKOuIu7qQQbeytIA6P6HT9_iIRt8zNQvuw4P9vbNjgUCpI6vfZGsjk3XuCVoB_bAIhvuBcQh9ePH2yEwS5reR-NrG1PsqzobnZZuigKCoDmuOb_UDx1DiVyNCbMBlEG7UzTQwLf5NP6HaRHx027URJeZvPAWY7zjHlSOuKoS_d1yUveaBFIgZqPWLCg44ck4gvik45HsNVWT9zYfT74dvUS
         SrMSR-SHFT7Hy1XjbVXpHJHNNAXpPoGoWXTuc0BxMsB4cqjfJqoftFGOG4x32vEzakArLPxAKwGvkvu0jToAyvSQ
e      : AQAB
x5c    : {MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQWHw7h/Ysh6hPcXpnrJ0N8DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAtMSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4XDTIwMDQyNzAwMDAwMFoXDTI1MDQyNzAwMDAwMFowLTErMCkGA1UEAxMiYWNjb3VudHMuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBB
         QADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALhz3sIYOFgt3i1T5BBZY+0Q7WimFlwiORviz1c7DCjriLu6kEG3srSAOj+h0/f4iEbfMzUL7sOD/b2zY4FAqSOr32RrI5N17glaAf2wCIb7gXEIfXjx9shMEua3kfjaxtT7Ks6G52WbooCgqA5rjm/1A8dQ4lcjQmzAZRBu1M00MC3+TT+h2kR8dNu1ESXmbzwFmO84x5UjriqEv3dclL3mgRSIGaj1iwoOOHJOIL4
         pOOR7DVVk/c2H0++Hb1EkqzEkfkhxU+x8tV421V6RyRzTQF6T6BqFl07nNAcTLAeHKo3yaqH7RRjhuMd9rxM2pAKyz8QCsBr5L7tI06AMr0kCAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFOI7M+DDFMlP7Ac3aomPnWo1QL1SMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBv+8rBiDY8sZDBoUDYwFQM74QjqCmgNQfv5B0Vjwg20HinERjQeH24uAWzyhWN9++Fm
         eY4zcRXDY5UNmB0nJz7UGlprA9s7voQ0Lkyiud0DO072RPBg38LmmrqoBsLb3MB9MZ2CGBaHftUHfpdTvrgmXSP0IJn7mCUq27g+hFk7n/MLbN1k8JswEODIgdMRvGqN+mnrPKkviWmcVAZccsWfcmS1pKwXqICTKzd6WmVdz+cL7ZSd9I2X0pY4oRwauoE2bS95vrXljCYgLArI3XB2QcnglDDBRYu3Z3aIJb26PTIyhkVKT7xaXhXl4Ogrbm
         Qon9/O61G2dzpjzzBPqNP}
issuer : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0
```

(and there are more records in the `keys` array...)

How could I please search for the record with `kid = "SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI"` and then return its `x5c` property?

Is the following a good way to find the record (I am confused by `-expand`, does it strip the outside JSON object and return just the `keys` array?) and then how to access its `x5c` property please?

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys |
>> ConvertFrom-Json |
>> Select-Object -expand keys |
>> Where-Object -Property kid -Eq SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI

kty    : RSA
use    : sig
kid    : SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI
x5t    : SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI
n      : uHPewhg4WC3eLVPkEFlj7RDtaKYWXCI5G-LPVzsMKOuIu7qQQbeytIA6P6HT9_iIRt8zNQvuw4P9vbNjgUCpI6vfZGsjk3XuCVoB_bAIhvuBcQh9ePH2yEwS5reR-NrG1PsqzobnZZuigKCoDmuOb_UDx1DiVyNCbMBlEG7UzTQwLf5NP6HaRHx027URJeZvPAWY7zjHlSOuKoS_d1yUveaBFIgZqPWLCg44ck4gvik45HsNVWT9zYfT74dvUS
         SrMSR-SHFT7Hy1XjbVXpHJHNNAXpPoGoWXTuc0BxMsB4cqjfJqoftFGOG4x32vEzakArLPxAKwGvkvu0jToAyvSQ
e      : AQAB
x5c    : {MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQWHw7h/Ysh6hPcXpnrJ0N8DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAtMSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4XDTIwMDQyNzAwMDAwMFoXDTI1MDQyNzAwMDAwMFowLTErMCkGA1UEAxMiYWNjb3VudHMuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBB
         QADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALhz3sIYOFgt3i1T5BBZY+0Q7WimFlwiORviz1c7DCjriLu6kEG3srSAOj+h0/f4iEbfMzUL7sOD/b2zY4FAqSOr32RrI5N17glaAf2wCIb7gXEIfXjx9shMEua3kfjaxtT7Ks6G52WbooCgqA5rjm/1A8dQ4lcjQmzAZRBu1M00MC3+TT+h2kR8dNu1ESXmbzwFmO84x5UjriqEv3dclL3mgRSIGaj1iwoOOHJOIL4
         pOOR7DVVk/c2H0++Hb1EkqzEkfkhxU+x8tV421V6RyRzTQF6T6BqFl07nNAcTLAeHKo3yaqH7RRjhuMd9rxM2pAKyz8QCsBr5L7tI06AMr0kCAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFOI7M+DDFMlP7Ac3aomPnWo1QL1SMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBv+8rBiDY8sZDBoUDYwFQM74QjqCmgNQfv5B0Vjwg20HinERjQeH24uAWzyhWN9++Fm
         eY4zcRXDY5UNmB0nJz7UGlprA9s7voQ0Lkyiud0DO072RPBg38LmmrqoBsLb3MB9MZ2CGBaHftUHfpdTvrgmXSP0IJn7mCUq27g+hFk7n/MLbN1k8JswEODIgdMRvGqN+mnrPKkviWmcVAZccsWfcmS1pKwXqICTKzd6WmVdz+cL7ZSd9I2X0pY4oRwauoE2bS95vrXljCYgLArI3XB2QcnglDDBRYu3Z3aIJb26PTIyhkVKT7xaXhXl4Ogrbm
         Qon9/O61G2dzpjzzBPqNP}
issuer : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0
```

Comment: Have you tried storing this output in a variable then using `$var.kid; $var.x5c`?

Comment: Ah, that works, thank you! I thought I need some `| Select-Property` but could not find such operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is everyday powershell.  Pipe to that.  It looks like x5c is an array too.

```
| select -expand x5c
```

Comment: Actually your answer suits me better, because I have been able to call `$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $x5c -AsPlainText -Force` (I plan to save it as a secret into a keyvault). While when I first tried to use `.x5c` - I was having the error `Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'`

Answer (score 2):

Store the output of the function in a variable like:

```
$var = Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys | ConvertFrom-Json
```

then take the "keys" and "x5c" part of the variable with:

```
$var.keys; $var.x5c
```